# Did the colors of the vote counts become lighter just now?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, design, vote-count, accessibility

I just noticed that the colors of the split vote counts have become lighter than they used to:

> [image: Lighter colors of vote counts]

(ignore the "(6.1%)", that's a user script)

Is this intentional?

Comment: @AaronShekey This is a support question, not a bug report or feature request. As such, the tag isn't applicable.

Comment: This is a feature request. If it's not, remove the last paragraph.

Comment: @Shadow9 It's not a feature request if the change was intentional, which it is. In any case, though, I've removed that paragraph. (Do note: [tag:possible-bug] is a synonym of [tag:support].) Also, [tag:status-bydesign] only applies to bug reports; the proper tag is [tag:status-declined] if the request is not to be implemented.

Comment: Maybe we should create a "fait accompli" tag.

Comment: People here wanting change: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343370/399694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change was intentional. They're now aligned with our branded colors. Before it was hardcoded CSS values of `green` and `maroon`.

Comment: The new colors are not in compliance with accessibility guidelines (and by token, U.S. law): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343370/new-colors-for-vote-counts-are-not-accessible-please-make-them-darker