# New colors for vote counts are not accessible; please make them darker

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, vote-count, accessibility

A new change [rolled out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343367/did-the-colors-of-the-vote-counts-become-lighter-just-now/343369#343369) to replace the vote count colors from hardcoded CSS values to branded colors.

However, these new colors are not in compliance with WCAG accessibility guidelines. In particular, the upvote color is way too bright:

> [image: New upvote/downvote split count colors]

(ignore the percentage above the downvote arrow; that's [a user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/8555/request-for-user-script-to-calculate-wilson-confidence-ratings-for-posts))

In particular, the [upvote number has a contrast ratio of just 2.38:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=5eba7d&bcolor=FFFFFF), which is below the 4.5:1 minimum for main text or even the 3:1 minimum for large text in WCAG 2 Level AA. The [downvote contrast ratio is 3.81:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=de535e&bcolor=FFFFFF), which is above the minimum for large text but below that for main text. Still, though, it would be nicer if it was darker as well.

It's worth noting that accessibility is [required](https://www.boia.org/blog/is-website-accessibility-required-under-the-ada) under the U.S. Americans with Disabilities Act, so this color may be in violation of that law.

Comment: [Related](https://contrastrebellion.com/). I recommend that they hire underslept designers with old monitors and old eyes in old lighting. It's the only way the whizkidz will stop coding up annoyingly low-contrast colors that work only for fifteen-year-olds. That, or citing violations of the U.S. Americans with Disabilities Act. Why do these simple matters of common sense always seem to require demand letters from lawyers hand-delivered  before anybody pays attention?

Comment: +1 When I turned on my computer just now and noticed this, it looked really bright to me. Not unreadable for me (very nearsighted but otherwise fine), but it just looks horribly faded, and I can see how it could be inaccessible to others.

Comment: FWIF, I cannot properly read vote summaries (small green rectangle with white text)...

Comment: We should be thankful it's not animated. Pretty sure it will be soon.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The specific issue reported in that question was resolved when SE rolled out new unified themes for all sites. The new unified theme uses a contrast ratio of 10.46:1 for the title text, which is more than Level AAA compliant even for main text.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog cool great to know! I've stopped using the default CSS a long time ago when have no idea how Stack Exchange is supposed to look like nowadays :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This instance has been [improved](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=3D8F58&bcolor=FFFFFF).

With regards to all of the other instances of colors that could have improved accessibility: We are aware that huge areas of our product are not yet within the WCAG spec. Right now we are working on a refactor of the way that we handle styles on our front-end that has been a long time coming. This refactor (when complete) will allow us to address contrast issues across our sites in a much easier and maintainable way.

While our ultimate aim is to improve and standardize accessibility across the site, in some places it may get worse before it gets better (due to unintended consequences of the refactor).

We thank you for your patience and appreciate your continued push for adherence to accessibility standards.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343794/282094) is probably what the change was attempting (and failed?) to address. People set their monitors to differing brightness and contrast levels, or use *dark mode* to reduce eyestrain. We should be able to get help here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/75149/how-many-more-people-do-i-reach-if-we-build-a-website-that-reaches-wcag-level-aa and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=WCAG+ and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baccessibility%5D+%5BWCAG%5D&mixed=0.

Comment: +1 and another textbook example from Yaakov on how to do communications *right*: answers the question (and addresses the motivation behind the question); tells us what's happening behind the scenes, ***why*** it's happening, and what negative impacts we should be prepared for; and explicitly says that staff are prepared and will act when we report issues and regressions. Great job again, I hope others are taking note.

Answer (score 8):

For reference, I list the colors below:

1. The gray used in the up/down arrow, unclicked star and number, and timeline icon is [#BBC0C4](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=BBC0C4&bcolor=FFFFFF) with a contrast ratio of **1.83:1**.
2. The large gray number is darker, and colored [#6A737C](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=6A737C&bcolor=FFFFFF) with a contrast ratio of **4.82:1**.
3. The gray loading circle icon uses [#EFF0F1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=EFF0F1&bcolor=FFFFFF) with a contrast ratio of **1.14:1** and [#BEC4C7](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=BEC4C7&bcolor=FFFFFF) with a contrast ratio of **1.76:1**.  [Approximate colors.]
4. The new green is [#5EBA7D](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=5eba7d&bcolor=FFFFFF) with a contrast ratio of **2.38:1**.
5. The new red is [#DE5363](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=DE5363&bcolor=FFFFFF) with a contrast ratio of **3.8:1**.
6. The yellow clicked star and number is [#CEA51B](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=CEA51B&bcolor=FFFFFF) with a contrast ratio of **2.32:1**.
7. ***Meta.SE***: The blue clicked icon is [#17A7DB](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=17A7DB&bcolor=FFFFFF) with a contrast ratio of **2.76:1**.

   This is different at different sites.  E.g.:

   1. ***StackOverflow*** uses a reddish [#F48024](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=F48024&bcolor=FFFFFF) with a contrast ratio of **2.63:1**.
   2. ***Math.SE*** uses a navy blue [#0F3559](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=0F3559&bcolor=FFFFFF) with a contrast ratio of **12.54:1**.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't really care about contrast ration for shapes as they can be easily discerned since they're large blocks. On the other hand, *text* with a small contrast ratio is hard to read, and its contrast ratio should be high. (The first sentence is why the contrast ratio minimum for large text is more lenient than that for small text.)

Comment: I understand you are primarily interested in text; others might additionally be interested in other design aspects, e.g., consistency, color schemes.  I just include this for reference [to help people have informed opinions].

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog If they are going to approach this from the point of view of attempting to be compliant with WCAG, then they should be targeting WCAG 2.1, which does have a [minimum 3:1 contrast ratio requirement for User Interface Components and Graphical Objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#x1-4-11-non-text-contrast).

Comment: The light greys for unclicked arrows etc are fine, the linked guidance explicitly says ***"except for inactive components"***, and turning up the contrast too high on these risks creating UX problems: confusing users about what is clicked and what isn't, which is [a problem we have seen before and don't want to re-create](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3011/voting-arrows-look-selected-when-theyre-not).