# Inbox notification text should be darker

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, global-inbox, accessibility

The notification font color was recently changed from black to gray (`#6A737C`):

[image: global inbox dropdown, text written in grey]

At least for me, the notifications are hard to read now. I suggest changing the color back to black.

Comment: The text is [compliant with WCAG 2 Level AA, but not AAA](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=6A737C&bcolor=FFFFFF) (a contrast ratio of 4.82:1, *barely* above the Level AA requirement). However, font smoothing on many systems (not depicted in your screenshot) can make the text appear lighter than its actual color, so I agree with your request to make it darker (and make it Level AAA compliant).

Comment: @Yaakov just curious, do you have a graphic designer that decide the colors?

Comment: @Shadow9 all new colors going up on the site come from our [standard palette](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/colors), and we try to coordinate color changes with the design team. We are right now [refactoring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343758/51) and taking care of some tech debt related to styles (which is the cause for the the regression here).