# Code highlighting colors were changed. Intentional or not?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design, syntax-highlighting

Apparently the code highlighting colors were recently changed.

Given that we've [had](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340205/tag-labels-are-hard-to-read-since-the-font-color-was-changed-should-the-change) a [few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343614/inbox-notification-text-should-be-darker) coloring bugs recently, I wonder if the change is intentional or not.

If it not intentional, I suggest rolling it back. The old colors look a lot better to me.

---

Compare [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222014056/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array) (old theme) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array) (new theme).

Or, as a screenshot. The top image is the old theme, the bottom one is the new one.

[image: pic]

---

UPD: The theme was updated again, this is how it looks now.

[image: pic]

Comment: I noticed the change earlier and I hope I get used to it. Right now, I don't like the (new) color(s).

Comment: I think that the new color scheme makes it much more readable, but that's probably a matter of taste.

Comment: Not a fan of the bright red, but - I think I'll pick my battles.

Comment: @einpoklum Btw, they've changed it to be less bright after I've posted this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: If you can add the newer change to your post, that would be nice.

Comment: @einpoklum Sure, done.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Now it's fine by me.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yep, these changes are intentional. We had to move some variables around to clean up our CSS. These were matched with the closest re-usable color values we have in our design system.

[image: Color shift]

Comment: I think this is, on balance, an improvement. I'm glad you worked hard to keep the closest colors to the old scheme as possible. The effort shows. My primary concern here is with the fifth color from the left. It used to be a very saturated deep blue, closer to purple than to green. Now it's a very desaturated dark blue, closer to green than to purple. That would be fine in the abstract, but in practice it is too close to the color right next to it. Since these colors get used for keywords and user-defined types in code, which often occur adjacently, being able to distinguish them is important!

Comment: The Stack Exchange SVG icon available for download uses #f48023 as opposed to --orange.  The logo and the talent logo's both have the correct color.  Seen a lot of changes in color popping up. figured I would bring it up here, rather than make a question over such a minuscule lack of blue.

Comment: Interesting, why is `.typ` not using a color variable though? It's still the original `#2B91AF`, or was it reverted in response to Cody's feedback?

Comment: The middle red is not in the stacks: https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/colors/#red Am I wrong? The red is now `red-600`, but it would be better if it was `red-700` or `red-800`. Could it be changed?

Comment: @AaronSkekey it seems fair to remove the actual hex values so long as you also remove/update the image here any time the colors change.

Comment: @Dharman: the color image is a little darker from the actual CSS colours.

Comment: @TylerH: the image is not actually *accurate*; the middle swatch is `#8f2629`, not the actual red-600 (`#c02d2e`) color used, for example. But it is consistently darker.

Comment: I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/mjpieters/details/LYVWGLZ) comparing old and new, as well as a few alt styles using the same Stack colors.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's part of the reason I added a list of the actual hex values; so people could look at what was objectively true for the design at a given point in time. Without that, the colors image in the post is even more useless/inaccurate than it is now as soon as the colors change again.

Comment: And the colors are lighter than I thought would be used at first. I agree with Dharman here, `red-600` is *too light*. red-800 would be a lot easier on the eyes.

Comment: Ah, and `.prettyprint` is also left at the original `#393318`. Any reason not to have used `--black-800` there?

Comment: Have you by any chance messed up some of the link colours with this fix? On sites where the link colours are starkly different from the button colours (like [movies.se] or [worldbuilding.se]) the visited and hovered links suddenly have a very different colour (namely a tint similar to the button colour but evrry different from the normal link colour).

Comment: @ChrissaysReinstateMonica There's a follow-up PR to fix that particular bug. Lots of moving parts today!

Comment: Ah, good to hear it's on the radar, though. Thank you.

Comment: The mobile and desktop versions seem to use a different colour palette, this is now extremely low contrast for VB languages on mobile (although they are fine on desktop)

Answer (score 6):

I believe the red and orange are too bright. I would propose the following colors to be used.

```css
.prettyprint {
    color: var(--black-800); /* was #393318 */
}
.str, 
.lit, 
.tag {
    color: var(--red-800); /* was --red-600 */
}
.kwd,
.dec {
    color: var(--blue-800);
}
.com {
    color: var(--black-400);
}
.typ {
    color: var(--powder-600); /* was #2B91AF */
}
.pun,
.pln {
    color: var(--black-750);
}
.atn {
    color: var(--orange-600); /* was --orange-500 */
}
.atv {
    color: var(--blue-600);
}
```

Comment: powder-600 is quite close to the blue-800 used for keywords and declarations. I find powder-500 to provide better contrast there. Anyway, added [to my pen](https://codepen.io/mjpieters/full/LYVWGLZ).

Comment: I can dig these changes. I've implemented them, @Dharman. Sticking with the aqua for now to ruffle fewer feathers. There's a way bigger opportunity to revisit syntax highlighting entirely, but not today.

Comment: What's better than a Codepen—especially one with production Stack Overflow CSS? Nice work.

Comment: @AaronShekey: now with even more reliance on the production SO CSS, by just including `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css` and `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/primary.css` into the pen.