# Make visited post titles a more distinct color on Meta.SE

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks, title

When you visit a post (eg. from `/questions` or from the home page), the link to that post is changed to be a different color to mark that you've visited it.

The benefit of this is that it visibly tells you whether you've already seen a post or not– but this only works if the two colors are distinct enough; you have to be able to tell them apart.

On Meta Stack Exchange, these two colors are **much** too similar:

| [image: Screenshot of /questions on Meta Stack Exchange with two posts visible, there's a previously visited post on top, and a never-visited post on bottom] |
| --- |

(The visited post is the top one, and the unvisited is below.)

The default color is `#4e82c2`, and the visited color is `#36649d`.

[image][image]

When placed side-by-side, the contrast isn't as bad, but when it's text on Meta's white background, they heavily blend together.

Being able to barely tell the colors apart completely defeats the purpose of this feature.

**Can the visited link color be updated to something more distinct?**

---

I put together a userscript to fix it purely to my own liking, since it's as simple as overriding a couple CSS selectors:

```css
.s-post-summary--content-title.s-link:visited,
.s-post-summary--content-title .s-link:visited {
    color: #838383 !important;
}
```

[image][image]

[image: Another screenshot of /questions on Meta Stack Exchange with two posts visible, there's a previously visited post on top, and a never-visited post on bottom]

But it would be really great if it was made more useable for everyone by design, with a color that appropriately addresses accessibility guidelines (I don't think the `#838383` gray I used necessarily does that).

Comment: Already a long-standing feature request: [Visited links should be more visible](/q/52942/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon That's definitely related; that request opens with "*This is mainly for Stack Overflow*" and actually _predates_ [the split of Meta.SO and Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-meta-of-its-own).

Comment: I'd upvote for the desire to change to a better visited-links color, but the suggested grey color is inappropriate, so I'm not voting. The suggested grey has only a 3.79:1 contrast ratio to the background, and, IMO, doesn't provide a significant color distinction vs the various normal text colors.

Comment: @Makyen Does my edit address your concerns? I hadn't intended to offer the gray as a solution– simply as the alternative I've personally chosen to use in the meantime (which is [significantly more distinct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1KDN.png) than the current color choice, if lacking in contrast).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visited links should be more visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52942/visited-links-should-be-more-visible)

Comment: Dupes and related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353614/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372651#comment1244624_372651 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371444/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344301/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315249/282094 - but they are old enough to warrant a new request.

Comment: Related: [Colors update: A more detailed look](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390761/335251) – the visited-link color was mentioned in feedback there, and in the updates to the post itself.

Comment: @V2Blast the colour difference is still inadequate.

Comment: To reduce eye-strain, I almost always use my phone browser's dark theme (Samsung Internet browser on a Galaxy S9). Those two blue blocks are almost indistinguishable in that theme. Of course, SE aren't obliged to cater for custom dark themes, but it would be nice if the site designs were a little more robust to client-side contrast modifications. Traditionally, visited links change *hue* slightly (eg, from blue to purple). It's *possible* to make hue changes that are visible to most forms of colour blindness.