# Tables on blog are incredibly hard to read in dark mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, accessibility, dark-mode

[This blog article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/) has a table, and so do other blog entries.

Tables look similar in all of them, and are very hard to read when viewing the blog in dark mode, as per screenshot below:

> [image: table in dark mode]

Do note it's not a userscript or custom style, the blog itself has a "toggle dark mode" button on top:

> [image: dark mode button]

Comment: @YaakovEllis, when looking into the table design, you might want to take a look at my linked question here at the same time: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343800/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be looking a bit better now, let us know if you see any others that look weird.

After:

[image]