# Tables on blog articles are not responsive

Tags: bug, blog, accessibility, responsive-design

In addition to my [previous question about the blog's design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343794/tables-on-blog-are-incredibly-hard-to-read-in-dark-mode):

I just browsed the article I linked there on a mobile device. Which yields a nice and responsive page. Except for tables, they maintain their original (unresponsive) size. Graphs (which I believe is basically an image) on the other hand does scale down to fit my screen.

[image: Screenshot of the responsive blog showing a scaled graph and an unscaled table]

Edit:

After a redesign tables now are responsive, but also fill the width of the site, which is not always needed:

[image]

To produce this image I requested the desktopversion through my browser (Chrome) settings.

Comment: Huh. Looks like the blog is responsive, but they forgot to install a responsive table WordPress plugin. :(

Comment: Could you link to the blog where this happens, please?

Comment: @Stormblessed https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/

Comment: Addressed this when I updated [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343794/tables-on-blog-are-incredibly-hard-to-read-in-dark-mode/343834#343834). Looking better on your device?

Comment: @DavidLongworth please see my edit of the question.

Comment: @DavidLongworth, I've addressed the remainder of the question in [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343841/282094).

Answer (score 1):

@DavidLongworth, there remains the problem mentioned in the question regarding the [graphs](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/) in dark mode:

Example:

[image: Stack Exchange Blog - Dark Mode - Graphs]

Applying a [naive inversion](https://pinetools.com/invert-image-colors) to the graph produces this *better* (but not perfect) result:

[image: Inverted - Stack Exchange Blog - Dark Mode - Graphs]

The *best* result would come from not simply inverting the black and white, but instead assigning them to the dark gray background and text colors.

For a simple fix the inversion is less blinding and more inline with the brightness of the rest of the webpage than leaving it as-is. The division lines would benefit from being lighter, possibly wider.