# "The Overflow" blog is nearly impossible to read in dark mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

The latest issue of "The Overflow" is [on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/06/the-overflow-12-plain-text/?cb=1), and is formatted as a table. In the site-specified dark mode, it is difficult to read:

[image: The Overflow screenshot]

Similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343794/tables-on-blog-are-incredibly-hard-to-read-in-dark-mode), it seems related to the fact that the whole thing is formatted as a table.

Note that this is a site setting, not a user-side dark mode:

[image: "Dark Mode" toggle]

Comment: You included a screenshot, so I'm reluctant to downvote, but, no repro here. I see light text on dark background, as I would expect.

Comment: @SOLO looks like they just fixed it. The source indicates it was updated at UTC 17:25, about an hour after I posted.

Comment: ...and now that it's legible, I also see that links 4-6 are repeats of 1-3.

Comment: @LShaver: Relevant question: [The Overflow's latest blog content is duplicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344720/the-overflows-latest-blog-content-is-duplicated) (now fixed)