# The Overflow's latest blog content is duplicated

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog

The latest issue of [The Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/06/the-overflow-12-plain-text/?cb=1) blog has some duplicated sections beneath the **From the blog** category.

[image]

As you can see, the top three links are completely duplicated in the next three links.

On a weird note: ASP.NET is hyperlinked in the second link, but not the fifth.

I'm wondering if this was an accidental copy and paste, or if there was supposed to be different content on the duplicated lines.

Comment: The first three links look like they were intended to go through a tracking URL and the second three are not.

Comment: There's a [comment from the author](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/06/the-overflow-12-plain-text/#comment-645290) about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this has been fixed.

[image]

Much better!