# New red/green background in revision history is too light and not visible

Tags: feature-request, design, revisions-list, accessibility

Along the same lines as [New red background for deleted posts is too light and not visible on high-contrast screens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344873/345161) the new(?) red/green paragraph colouring in the revision history is also too light and barely visible.

[image]

The green isn't that bad but still not that visible.

Comment: FWIW, the background isn't even discernably green on my monitor.

Comment: @DavidW I can see the green on one monitor not the other. Had to move my browser over to take the screenshot just so it was clear.

Comment: Well, don't blame SE for your badly calibrated monitors ;P.

Comment: Which monitor it's on shouldn't matter wrt. taking the screenshot. It's not that the framebuffer contains different data for the pixels on your two different monitors. It's that how the framebuffer ends up visually displayed is different between your two monitors. A screenshot only cares what is in the framebuffer, not how the display actually looks. You should be able to view the screenshot, in whatever image viewer you use, and have it display differently between your two monitors.

Comment: @Makyen to clarify I moved it to my better monitor to make sure what I thought I was seeing, I was and then took the screenshot.

Comment: Could you please add a photograph (not screenshot) of what the colors looks like?  There's really no problem on my screen ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGQh4.jpg)).