# Bring back the deleted post shade

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

A few months ago (?) there were some changes to the site aesthetics, including toning down the use of a contrasting background for code and deleted posts.

I'd prefer they both come back, but the issue with code seems like a personal preference; I don't have a pragmatic argument and aren't interested in forcing my opinion about it on the world.

However, removing the pink tint on deleted posts is a step backward in practical terms.<sup>1</sup>  It was very clear when something was deleted. I'm a mod, and for me there's a significant practical value to that.

Of course that the post has been deleted is not hidden -- there is still a banner clearly stating the fact.  The visual significance of this diminishes with the size of the post, however.

A common context for deletions are brand new users who post questions as answers.  Having a glaring visual element (the pink background) no doubt made something pop.  The banner of course is there, and you receive a notification.  Keep in mind, though, this is already someone who wrote up a question and clicked *Post Your **Answer***.  I think long term users may not realize how relatively complex (compared to eg. bb style forums) the SE interface is, and that a normal reaction to that would to to tune out things in accord with whatever you *think* you are looking at.

So: That's several pragmatic reasons to go with the contrasted background; I really don't see any for *not* doing so, meaning this seems like a sacrifice of functionality for trivial aesthetics.

---

1. There's a 10K rep bar on seeing deleted posts, so if you don't know what I'm on about that's probably why.  The bar does not apply to your own posts if deleted.

Comment: On which SE site(s) is this occurring? There are three sites on which I can see deleted posts, and on all three they still have the pink background.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either.

Comment: I've already reported this: [New red background for deleted posts is too light and not visible on high-contrast screens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344873/new-red-background-for-deleted-posts-is-too-light-and-not-visible-on-high-contra). They've made the background lighter, to the point where users with high display contrast can't see them.

Comment: @F1Krazy It's there, but a lighter shade, and thus not visible on high contrast screens. See the above duplicate, where I have screenshots.

Comment: Huh.  I have a 4K monitor set at 2K, and the browser is always on that one -- tried on another screen and say voila.  The contrast was not high (60/100) and the brightness was actually low (35/100).  Set the contrast to 50 and the brightness to 60 and now the pink is clear.